# how to get $dx\; dy=r\;dr\;d\theta$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

In polar coordinate how we can get $dx\;dy=r\;dr\;d\theta$?

with these parameters:

$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
$x=r\cos\theta$
$y=r\sin\theta$

Tanks.

Comment: If you want to know the intuition behind this, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/90350/8297) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37044/explain-iint-mathrm-dx-mathrm-dy-iint-r-mathrm-d-alpha-mathrm-dr) could be very useful.

Comment: The area of a circular sector with outer radius $r_o$, inner radius $r_i$ and "spread" $\Delta\theta$ is   $${\Delta\theta\over2}({r_o^2-r_i^2})
= {\Delta\theta\over2}({r_o +r_i }) ({r_o -r_i })={\Delta\theta } \cdot r_{avg}\Delta r\approx
r\Delta\theta\Delta r.  $$ 
When setting up a double integral, $r\,dr\,d\theta$  becomes your area element.

Comment: tanks guys. i just decided to remember that equation for exams:D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, under the change of coordinates $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$, the area element changes according to the formula: (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant))
$$du \;dv=\left|\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|dx\; dy,$$
where the Jacobaian is the determinant given by 
$$\left|\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|=\left|
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
  \end{array}
\right|.$$

Therefore, for polar coordinates $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, we have 
$$\left|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}\right|=\left|
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \\
  \end{array}
\right|=\left|
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & r\cos\theta \\
  \end{array}
\right|=r,$$
which implies that 
$$dx\; dy=r\;dr\; d\theta.$$

Comment: tanks paul your solution is straightforward

Answer (score 1):

If a circle has radius $r$, then an arc of $\alpha$ radians has length $r\alpha$.  So with an infinitesimal increment $d\theta$ of the angle, the length is the infinitesimal $r\;d\theta$.  And the arc is a right angles to the radius, which changes by the infinitesimal amount $dr$.  So the infinitesimal area involved is just the product $r\;dr\;d\theta$.

Comment: I would have thought that the radius $r$ is fixed...surely we are dealing with a fixed size circle?

Comment: Nevermind, I get what's happening now.